# How to avoid Log4J exploit?

Tags: java, log4j2

There is a serious security flaw in Log4J that has apparently been patched.  But I have not found an intelligible explanation as to how there could even be a security flaw in a logging framework.

It seems to have something to do with "Lookups".
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

But that is in a config file, not a log file that could be injected into?

Question.  How do I kill all clever stuff once and for all to prevent any future exploits?  I just want logging.

It smells like I need to remove any "$" signs but that is just a guess.  (One should also remove any \ns to avoid log file spoofing. I always write a very simple wrapper for the logging to be able to do this sort of thing.)

(I have a very simple shim that all log messages go through, so it is easy for me to remove all "$"s that are not in format strings.)

Comment: A link to the CVE would help.

Comment: *"How do I kill all clever stuff once and for all to prevent any future exploits."*  - Answer: the only way to be 100% sure that nobody else has made a mistake that makes logging insecure is to implement it yourself.  From the ground up.  Then you will only have yourself to blame.  (In more than one sense ...)

Comment: Here is an intelligible explanation: https://news.sophos.com/en-us/2021/12/12/log4shell-hell-anatomy-of-an-exploit-outbreak/.  The short version is: message substitution + a clever trick to get log4j to send HTTP request to the hacker's machine.

Comment: CVE-2021-44228 link for reference - http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2021-44228

Comment: Or a longer explanation https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2021/12/13/log4shell-explained-how-it-works-why-you-need-to-know-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: The right place to ask is https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The only way to prevent vulnaribilites caused by lookups is to disable them completely.

According to log4j2 team, the way to do that is by appending Java parameter

`-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true`

This definitely fixes the ability to call lookups by putting ${...} sequence  s in the user input (like in URLs that are logged).

Unfortunately, the lookups are applied to the logged sequence, even if you use parameters or log exception stack traces. The lookups sequeces in your code are not dangerous, because they are controllable. But those that come from user are not predictable. If you log 'wrong username: xxx', you have no idea, what the user can type to exploit another vulnaribility.

However, you can't be sure there are no other grave errors in the framework, so switching to other logging framework is reasonable.

A good candidate is [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), which is started by the original author of the Log4j. The developer states clearly, his framework has nothing to do with the security issues introduced in Log4j2:

> Unless specified otherwise, when we say log4j we mean log4j 1.x. We
> should also like to emphasize that logback is unrelated to log4j 2.x.
> It does not share code nor vulnerabilities with log4j 2.x.

The bug [is apparently fixed](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) in the version 2.16.0, however it addresses only that particular vulnaribility, and the dangerous lookup feature was not removed.

According to the [Sophos Report](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2021/12/13/log4shell-explained-how-it-works-why-you-need-to-know-and-how-to-fix-it/),

> The updated version of Log4j still supports the potentially dangerous
> what-you-see-is-not-what-you-get system of string “lookups”, but
> network-based JNDI connections, whether on the same machine or
> reaching out to somewhere else, are no longer enabled by default.

In other words, log4j2 still remains unsecure, but not as ridiculously insecure as previously.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have been clear that I have my own simple shim for logging, which can then go to either CommonsLogging or SLF4J, and thence Log4J.   So in my shim I can remove all "$"  from messages that are not in format strings.  Is that enough?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that anyone would apply lookups to the logged sequence, but then, worse things have been done.  It is also important to deal with "\n" to prevent spoofing messages which has been used in obscure attacks.

Comment: Any reason why System.setProperty(log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups, true) would not work?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify that the real fix is to upgrade to Log4j 2.15.0, nd that specifying `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` is a workaround.

Comment: I'm using highcharts extension on my project and it's using log4j version-1.2.14. Is this version vulnerable too?

Comment: @NehaJaggi probably not, because lookups are a 'feature' of version 4-2. But taking into account the amount of incompetence and negligence involved, I'd say no java logging framework can be trusted anymore unless it undergo a detailed security audit from the 3rd party.

Comment: @Tuntable See https://twitter.com/apenwarr/status/1469440349496287232

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Thanks for the response. Actually 'java' is not be installed in system but we're using some library which are using log4j in compiled way. Then how I can I detect that it's vulnerable or not is there any way to check?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually, I think that the real solution is to do both.  The upgrade only fixes the current bug, not the underlying problem which is to expand stuff in the logged sequence.

Answer (score 1):

For security issues like this one it makes sense to keep the up to date information in a single place.

Please refer to the official Log4j information about this vulnerability here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html
The document states several mitigation measures applicable for different versions of Log4j.

I realize that in general the StackOverflow convention is to have explicit steps and examples in the answer here on StackOverflow, rather than link to external documentation, but  I believe that sensitive security flaws should be an exception.

Comment: Thanks, but I read that link and it does not explain anything really.  I suspect that the real issue is that they are parsing stuff out of the logged sequence.

Comment: The security page has been updated and will be updated further if additional information becomes available. The home page also has an [explanation of the issue](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html#CVE-2021-44228).

Comment: Good point. The handling of log4j2 security questions is now discussed on Meta, care to state this position there? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413724/2945027

Comment: No. I don't think anything on the log4j2 page can be trusted anymore. They proved the're too incompetent in security area.